# Written a method with two int arguments. How to declare further local int variables using the information provided below

Tags: java, int, bluej, local-variables

I have written a public instance method moveBy() whose first argument is an int representing the distance to move and whose second argument is a char representing the direction in which to move. It should return no value.

Table 1: Directions and corresponding x and y increments

```
         Direction   xInc    yInc (this is not a code)

Right      'R'        1       0

Left       'L'       -1       0

Up         'U'        0      -1

Down       'D'        0       1
```

I need to begin by declaring local int variables xInc and yInc and use the table above to set these for the appropriate increments depending on the supplied argument for direction.

This is what I have done so far: please if someone can correct me and help me! many thanks

```
public void moveBy(int distance, char direction)

 {

int xInc = 0;

int yInc = 0;
}
```

or I tried this for the first bit but it says' identifier expected'.

```
int xInc = 1,-1, 0, 0
int yInc = 0, 0, -1, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the error comes from the syntax your are using to declare variables :

```
int xInc = 1; // variable xInc can take only one value (1) and it should be an integer.
```

Same for `yInc`

If you are going to use Java, it's good to start think with [OOP Principles](https://howtodoinjava.com/oops/object-oriented-principles/)

What you want to acheive is storing a Move with Coordinates with X and Y axis and a direction.

Start model this in an class :

```
public class Move {

    private int xcoordinate;
    private int ycoordinate;
    private String direction // better if it a enum

    public Move(int xInc, int yInc, String direction) {
         this.xcoordinate = xInc;
         this.ycoordinate = yInc;
         this.direction = direction;
    }

    // getter
    public String getDirection() {
         return direction;
    }
}
```

When you model a move in a class you can use it to make moves ! To get information take advantage of getters.

```
Move firstMove = new Move(2, 1, "R"); // move 2 in x axis and 1 in y axis, in right direction
Move secondMove = new Move(3, -1, "L"); // move 3 in x axis and -1 in y axis, in left direction
```

you can know get rid of of `moveBy()` method because Move class embed in itself the move process.

Instead have a method `makeMove(Move move)`and implements the moving process in it.

Comment: Hi Hassam thanks for your help. I am actually doing an apprenticeship and this is sort of like homework I was given by my boss. I basically have to stick with the guidelines. So i have to keep moveBy also I already have a class called StickFigure with variables circle, triangle and rectangle which represent the head, body and leg. As well as private int xPos and yPos. So now how would I go about making the changes? jzk bro

Comment: I need more details to help you? Are you obliged to use the moveBy method?

Comment: yes I have to use that and the information in the table to move my class Stick Figures, variables triangle,circle and rectangle which make up the class.

Comment: Having the whole information in the question would be great i will be able to help you